# R package development - adding an image to the help file ?PackageName

Tags: r, roxygen2

I'm building an R Package and want to include an icon for the package that shows in the upper right of the main help page when user does:

```
 > ?PackageName
```

Where do I have to save the image and what syntax is needed in the R/PackageName.R file that looks like:

```
#' @docType package
#' @name PackageName
#' @title Package Title
#' @author Me
```

My build process is using RStudio > Build > Clean and rebuild